# Interpreting regression results for predicting airline prices

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, r-squared

I am building a model to predict the rise/fall of airline ticket prizes.I have 61 predictor variables(most of them are global stock market indices) and one response variable, i.e ticket prize of the airline. I have only 9 observations. My regression results look like this.

[image: Regression results]

The Minitab software automatically detects variables with high multicollinearity and omits them from the analysis. I am left with the results shown in the image. The predicted $R^2$ is shown as 0.00 % which shouldn't be the case. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: what is VIF  in coefficients table ?

Comment: Rsquare  0.00% is not clear ? how do you obtain it ?

Comment: 9 observations is too little. If you had 9 independent features, you should have gotten 100% R squared. I guess you had some penalty on the coefficients. Anyway, even if you had 900 observations, it still would be too little, especially with such noisy features.

Comment: @user2089357. By noisy you mean multicolinearity?. If yes, then most of them have been eliminated by minitab.

Comment: By noisy, I mean that they don't actually contain that much information about air travel. You would want more relevant features - for example day of the year, holidays, weather, recent terrorist attacks, etc. But your main problem is that you need *much* more data - 9 observations is practically nothing. You could create 9 random features, and you would still get 100% R squared.

Comment: Also , is it because most of the features aren't relevant , I'm not getting the R2 predicted  value at all ?

Comment: It seems that you have introduced one or more spurious variables that result in spoil-sport.

Comment: think of adding tags : interpretation and prediction and delete regression.